# Is casting from Iterable<?> to Iterable<Object> always safe?

Tags: java, generics, casting

Is casting from `Iterable<?>` to `Iterable<Object>` always safe?

It looks like it is, since I can't see any way how to misuse it to produce an unexpected `ClassCastException`, but I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you should never need to cast from `Iterable<?>` to `Iterable<Object>`. As `Iterable` is a producer, an `extends` bounded wildcard like `Iterable<?>` should be sufficient for all purposes.

Comment: @newacct: I guess you're wrong, as I really had to cast. However, since then I rewrote the code and in the current version I could remove the cast and it compiles. So thanks!

Comment: In what situation would you have to cast? If you simply replace every occurrence of `Iterable<Foo>` in your program with `Iterable<? extends Foo>`, it should not affect its ability to compile.

Comment: @newacct: I can't reproduce it anymore. I guess, it was in a call to a JDK method, so I couldn't change the signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I know what bothered me:

```
Integer blown() {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Iterable<?> iterable = intList;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // This cast should be safe, shouldn't it?
    Iterable<Object> objectIterable = (Iterable<Object>) iterable;
    safeMethod(objectIterable);

    return intList.get(0);
}

// This method is definitely fine, no unchecked cast.
private void safeMethod(Iterable<Object> objectIterable) {
    if (objectIterable instanceof List) {
        List<Object> list = (List<Object>) objectIterable;
        list.add("blown!");
    }
}
```

So the cast is safe as long you don't upcast and don't let the unsafe thingy escape.

Comment: Ah so you can cast back to use a contravariant method. So a better answer to this question is "Yes, so long as you don't but yourself in a position to use contravariant methods"

Comment: @jozefg: Covariant and contravariant... if I ever could remember which is which!

Comment: @maaartinus It's easy if you break down the words: "co" means with, "contra" means against. A covariant type "subtypes" _with_ its generic: `Foo<A>` is a subtype of `Foo<B>` if `A` is a subtype of `B`. A contravariant type subtypes _against_ its generic: `Foo<A>` is a subtype of `Foo<B>` iff `A` is a _supertype_ of `B`.

Comment: @yshavit: That's perfect, you saved me from this ignorance.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of `Iterable`, yes, since it doesn't have any methods that take a `T`, only methods that return a `T` (well, via its iterator). **EDIT**: See below.

Java doesn't have a formal concept of covariant classes vs contravariant classes, which is why it can't distinguish between an `Iterable<T>` and a `List<T>` (the latter of which is *not* safe to cast from `List<?>` to `List<Object>`). Since it doesn't have this distinction, it's forced to warn you that the cast is potentially unsafe. After all, unsafe doesn't mean things *will* break, it just means that the compiler can't guarantee that they *won't*.

**EDIT:** maaartinus found a good counterexample. The above is only true if the Iterable is immutable; but of course, immutable types are generally covariant anyway (even if Java doesn't recognize that, since it doesn't recognize immutability).

Comment: Very good point about the return types of T vs parameters of type T.  Basically, casting of this type is safe if your generic type, T, only affects what comes out of an object and does not affect what goes into it.

Comment: @maaartinus How do you mean? You have a covariant class where as `List` is neither covariant or contravariant (it has methods which are one or the other)

Comment: @jozefg: I do a seemingly safe unsafe cast from `Iterable<?>` to `Iterable<Object>`. By passing the thing to an innocuous method it blows.